# NodeJs & MySql: results.insertId always 0 when the table id is a UUID

Tags: mysql, node.js, uuid

I'm inserting records to a `MySql` table using `NodeJs` `mysql` package, then trying to get the inserted record `id` by asking for `results.insertId`. But although the record is inserted correctly, the returned id is always zero.

The issue is probably that the table's `Primary Key` is a `UUID (BINARY 16)`. If I change it to `INT (11)` the `insertId` returns the correct value. So is there a way around it? Can I get the `insertId` if it's a `UUID`?

This is my code:

```
pool.query('insert into my_table (id, title) '
                    + ' values(uuid(), ?', [ title ],
  function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(results);
    }
 }
```

The full `results` object:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your id colum nis not AUTO_INCREMENT column. That is why you cannot use `insertId`

you may consider to generate `uuid` on code and insert it as parameter to your query.

or perform 2 separated queries:

```
SELECT UUID()
INSERT INTO my_table (id, title) VALUES ($uuid, ?)
```

Answer (score 2):

The insertId value you are checking is populated only in the case of a `auto_increment` key (which must be integer, not UUID). In that case the key is generated directly by the insert query, and is readable as last inserted id.
In your case, the UUID is note generated by the insert query, instead it is generated by the `uuid()` function.

You can work around this issues in two ways:

- You can generate the uuid explicitly in nodejs and use that value in the insert query
- You can create a stored procedure which generates the uuid, saves the record and returns the uuid.